# Wrap boost gzip compressor in easy to use function/class

Tags: c++, boost

I just discovered the boost gzip (de)compressor filter and wanted to wrap it in an easy to use function or class to open compressed files for reading/writing and give me something convertible to an `std::ostream`. Since the `boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream` cannot be copied or moved and I also need to keep the `std::ofstream` alive a function just returning, a `filtering_ostream` seems impossible. Instead I wrote a class which inherits from `std::ostream`. The class now looks like this:

```
class gzip_ofstream : public std::ostream
{
public:
  gzip_ofstream(const std::string& filename)
    : std::ostream(&m_buf),
      m_file(filename, ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary)
  {
    m_buf.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor());
    m_buf.push(m_file);
  }

private:
  std::ofstream m_file;
  boost::iostreams::filtering_ostreambuf m_buf;
};
```

I should probably add a check if the file was opened successfully but my main concern is the call to the `std::ostream` constructor. When the `std::ostream` contructor is called the `m_buf` object has not been initialized properly so I'm not sure if this code is valid. Is this well defined code and if not how do I fix it?

Comment: Why not swap order of declararion and construction? Ah, because you need inutialization.  How does this help with making a function that returns the filter ostream?  I guess it does not.  Considered multiple inheritance and an intermediate class that initializes the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not saying you should, but this in practice a situation where Base-From-Member is applied:

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member

Boost has it in Boost Utility:

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member

Their sample is:

```
#include <boost/utility/base_from_member.hpp>

#include <streambuf>  // for std::streambuf
#include <ostream>    // for std::ostream

class fdoutbuf
  : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    explicit fdoutbuf( int fd );
    //...
};

class fdostream
  : private boost::base_from_member<fdoutbuf>
  , public std::ostream
{
    // Helper typedef's
    typedef boost::base_from_member<fdoutbuf>  pbase_type;
    typedef std::ostream                        base_type;

public:
    explicit fdostream( int fd )
      : pbase_type( fd ), base_type( &member ){}
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A B and C classes.

C contains the filter.

B inherits from C, and contains the m_file.  It cobstructs m_file then initializes the filter.

A inherits first from B, then from the stream.  It constructs B (and hence the filter), then the stream.

A and B can probably be merged.